Assistance Required for Google Maps Restaurant List issues
I am reaching out to seek assistance with two critical issues I am experiencing on Google Maps.

Inaccessible Influencer Links in Restaurant Listings :
I have curated a list of the top restaurants in France on Google Maps. For each restaurant, I included a link in the comments section to an influencer's review which provides insights into why the restaurant is noteworthy. However, my clients are unable to access these links after clicking on the restaurant's name from the shared list. The links appear when viewing the overall list but are unclickable on the individual restaurant pages. This problem is significant for my business, and I need your guidance on how it can be resolved. Could you please advise or recommend me a developers look into this issue?

enter image description here
enter image description here

Restricting List Sharing and Editing :
Additionally, I want to ensure that the list of the best restaurants remains unmodifiable and unsharable by my clients. While I have successfully restricted editing abilities, I am unable to prevent clients from sharing the list. I would appreciate your support in disabling the sharing feature for this list.

Could you please connect me with a developer or a member who can assist me in resolving these issues promptly?
Thank you very much for your attention to these matters. I look forward to your swift response.
Best regards,
I tried to contact Google assistance, but cannot reach them correctly. I’m in contact with non professional employer which bring me automatic answers.
